# Encountering 'Account Limit Exceeded' Error When Opening App via Link

Tags: flutter, paytm, upi, phonepe

### Problem Description

I'm developing a mobile app that scans QR codes, extracts information from links in the following UPI format:

```
upi://pay?pa=RECIPIENT_UPI_ID&pn=RECIPIENT_NAME&mc=MERCHANT_CATEGORY_CODE&mode=02&purpose=00
```

My app allows for editing some details and initiates UPI (Unified Payments Interface) transactions. However, I'm encountering a specific issue:

- When I scan a QR code from my app and proceed to make a payment through a UPI app, I enter my UPI pin, but I receive an "Account Limit Exceeded" error within my app, and the payment fails.

### Details

- **Desired Flow:** The expected flow involves scanning a QR code, extracting information from links in the provided UPI format, editing as needed, presenting a list of UPI apps to choose from, entering a UPI pin, and successfully completing the payment.
- **Current Issue:** Instead, after entering the UPI pin, my app displays an "Account Limit Exceeded" error. Interestingly, if I scan the same QR code from a UPI app like Paytm, the payment goes through without any issues.

### What I've Tried

I've reviewed my code, ensured proper UPI link formatting as per the provided format, and confirmed that my app is correctly registered to handle UPI links. Despite these efforts, the "Account Limit Exceeded" error persists when initiating payments from within my app.

### Desired Outcome

I'm seeking guidance on resolving the "Account Limit Exceeded" error during the payment process from my app. I want to ensure that users can complete UPI transactions seamlessly as intended, just as they can when using standalone UPI apps like Paytm.

Any insights or suggestions for troubleshooting and resolving this specific issue are greatly appreciated.